# Issue with rel='imageName' when name contains a single quote

Tags: jquery, mysql, html, rel

I have a table on my page that shows cardname, cost, set, rarity. This information comes from a database table. When a user is hovering over any cardname in the table there is an image popping up of the card and as soon as the mouse is removed the image closes (using a jQuery script for this).

This is how the code of the cardname cells look:

```
<td><a href='#' class='screenshot' rel='cards/$cardname.jpg'>$cardname</a></td>
```

Everything works fine except when $cardname contains ' which messes up the code and prevents the image from showing (example of a cardname not working could be "Faith's Shield"). I tried to use ´ instead but that doesn't seem to work either.

I know that this is probably not the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do but I'm quite new to webprogramming and this seemed like a simple trick to make it work.

```
print "<table id='cardTable'>
                <tr>
                    <th>Add to deck</th>
                    <th>Cardname</th>
                    <th>Cost</th>
                    <th>Set</th>
                    <th>Rarity</th>
                </tr>";

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $cardname = $row['cardname'];
            $cost = $row['cost'];
            $set = $row['set'];
            $rarity = $row['rarity'];
            $idCard = $row['idCard'];

            print "<tr>
                    <td>
                    <form action='' method='post'>
                    <p><button type='submit' name='addCard' class='addCard' value='$idCard' title='Add card to deck'></button>
                    <select name='amount'>
                    <option value='1'>1</option>
                    <option value='2'>2</option>
                    <option value='3'>3</option>
                    <option value='4'>4</option>
                    </select></p>
                    </form>
                    </td>
                    <td><a href='#' class='screenshot' rel='cards/$cardname.jpg'>$cardname</a></td>
                    <td>$cost</td>
                    <td>$set</td>
                    <td>$rarity</td>
                </tr>";

        }
            print "</table>";
```

Comment: You have to encode the ('), what language are you using?

Comment: @devundef i don't think he's having an encoding issue. He's pulling the data from the DB, but the single quote is causing the rel='' attribute to prematurely terminate and break. He needs to escape the single quote or replace it (as rajat singhal suggests)

Comment: It's interesting that in the title of your question you use double quotes for the attribute value, which is exactly what would fix your problem.

Comment: Why are you using the `rel` attribute?

Comment: @Sam, that's i'm trying to say. My english is too bad! =D

Comment: I think a better solution is to build your application to not allow image names like "Faith's Shield" to be kept in your DB. This would avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: Double quotes doesn't fix it for what i've tried, edited the post with the code for the whole table

Comment: You can make your code simpler if you don't print HTML with PHP but embed PHP into HTML.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `rel` attribute this way (it's not conforming).

Answer (score 4):

Try surrounding the attribute values with double quotes instead (attrib="value").  Then it won't matter whether there's a single quote inside the value.  Also, replace double-quotes inside values with

```
&quot;
```

Comment: Always HTML escape the contents of your HTML attributes. You can get away with not doing this *most* of the time, but as you've discovered, not always.

Comment: Most languages provide some way for you to escape quotes within your strings.  For example, in PHP, you prepend the quote with a backslash (\) character.  Here's an example:  

`code` echo "this is a string containing a \"quoted\" word.";

Answer (score 2):

```
<td>
    <a href='#' class='screenshot' rel='cards/<?php echo str_replace("'", '', $cardname); ?>.jpg'></a>
</td>
```

And more appropriately, as suggested by Felix use `htmlspecialchars`, which will convert all of special chanacters..

```
<td>
    <a href='#' class='screenshot' rel='cards/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($cardname); ?>.jpg'></a>
</td>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `htmlspecialchars` be more appropriate? Also it is not for sure that OP is using PHP.

Comment: If you use it inside single quotes, you also have to pass the `ENT_QUOTES` flag (at least it's clear now that it is PHP ;))

Comment: Doesn't work, already using double quotes so this messes up the code, I edited my post with the whole table to make it more clear, thanks for helping out!

Comment: instead of `<td><a href='#' class='screenshot' rel='cards/$cardname.jpg'>$cardname</a></td>`...use ...`<td><a href='#' class='screenshot' rel='cards/".htmlspecialchars($cardname).".jpg'>".htmlspecialchars($cardname)."</a></td>`